# Error sintaxis en Volley con Kotlin

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, volley

```
class Principal:AppCompatActivity()
  {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

setContentView(R.layout.second_panel)

btnaccess.setOnClickListener {
    MySingleton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(GetJsonObjectRequest())
}

}  

fun GetJsonObjectRequest(): JsonObjectRequest {

val tokenUser = MainActivity.tokenAccess

val remesaCliente = remesaId.text.toString()

val url_2 = "https://ruta/recursos/operacion_enturnamiento/index.php?view=remesa/"+remesaCliente

val jsonObjectRequest = JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url_2, null,
    Response.Listener<JSONObject> { response ->
        viewResponse.text = "$response"
    },
    Response.ErrorListener { error ->
        viewResponse.text = "ERROR: %s".format(error.toString()) })
{
    override fun GetHeaders(): MutableMap<String, String> {
        val headers = HashMap<String, String>()
        headers.put("Token" ,tokenUser)
        return headers
    }
}

   return jsonObjectRequest
}
}
```

En el anterior código, se desea hacer una petición Volley al endpoint indicado concatenando un numero para la petición, la novedad esta a la hora de agregar los Headers al método. Android Studio muestra Errores en el Override y  en el `JsonObjectRequest`

Relaciono los errores retornados por Android Studio, vale aclarar que el `JsonObjectRequest` funciona sin problemas solo aparece el error al incluir la función `Override` para los headers

Error #1

> C:\Users\slait\AndroidStudioProjects\Firstapp\app\src\main\java\ap\control_inv\firstapp\Principal.kt:
> (34, 33): None of the following functions can be called with the
> arguments supplied: public constructor JsonObjectRequest(p0: Int, p1:
> String!, @Nullable p2: JSONObject?, p3: ((JSONObject!) -> Unit)!,
> @Nullable p4: ((VolleyError!) -> Unit)?) defined in
> com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest

Error #2

> C:\Users\slait\AndroidStudioProjects\Firstapp\app\src\main\java\ap\control_inv\firstapp\Principal.kt:
> (43, 13): Modifier 'override' is not applicable to 'local function'

Comment: Hola Que errores se muestran?, es importante mencionarlos, revisar [ask] y edita tu pregunta, saludos.

Comment: Hola buenas tardes, Acabo de  editar la pregunta con la información Adicional, muchas gracias